# Set a custom field as argument for .find() in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, dynamic, field

i'm doing an HTTP call to my api to retrieve documents from a mongodb and in the url i have two parameters: **campo** and **keyphrase**.
I wanna look for all the documents which have the parameter **campo** set to my **keyphrase**.
E.g: I have a few docs like this in my mongo:

```
classe: "4AT"
cognome: "XYZ"
email: "xyz.zyx@gmail.com"
idreg: "IUDQFEXFFR4DW133"
nome: "Francesco"
turni: ["g2t1", "g1t2", "g3t2"]
__v: 0
_id: "5c508d0b4810fc0ece8df2a9"
```

I call GET to "localhost:3000/nome/Francesco" and i wanna pick all the documents with value "Francesco" in field "nome".
But the problem is that the method .find() accepts parameters like:

```
.find({nome: keyphrase})
```

and not dynamical headers like i want. Is there any chance to do it?

PS: my Express code for get request, if it helps:

```
app.get("/api/ragazzi/:campo/:keyphrase",(req, res, next) => {
  let campo = req.params.campo.toLowerCase();
  let keyphrase = req.params.keyphrase;
  Ragazzo.find({campo : keyphrase})
    .then(documents =>{
      res.status(200).json({
        codice: "ok",
        risultato: documents
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});
});
```

Comment: What are you using to specify the api endpoint? Express?

Comment: yes express. the get method is something like:
app.get("/api/ragazzi/:campo/:keyphrase",(req, res, next) => {
  let campo = req.params.campo.toLowerCase();
  let keyphrase = req.params.keyphrase;
  Ragazzo.find({campo : keyphrase})
    .then(documents =>{
      res.status(200).json({
        codice: "ok",
        risultato: documents
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});
});

Hope you can see something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.find({ [campo] : keyphrase})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query based on the value of campo and keyphrase then create an object in beforehand and use it as the query

```
app.get("/api/ragazzi/:campo/:keyphrase",(req, res, next) => {
  let campo = req.params.campo.toLowerCase();
  let keyphrase = req.params.keyphrase;
  let query = {};
  query[campo] = keyphrase
  Ragazzo.find(query)
    .then(documents =>{
      res.status(200).json({
        codice: "ok",
        risultato: documents
      });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});
});
```

Comment: The other answer was shorter. Thanks anyway :3